# Excluding URLs from OpenAM Tomcat Agent Filter Mapping

Tags: tomcat, filter, opensso

The default web.xml configuration for OpenAM provides a filter-mapping that includes all URI's within a site:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Agent</filter-name>
    <display-name>Agent</display-name>
    <description>SJS Access Manager Tomcat Policy Agent Filter</description>
    <filter-class>com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Agent</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

How can I prevent one or more specific URI's from being used with this filter?  I would like to avoid extending the Filter class into one that accepts initialization parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure not enforced URIs on your agent.  It's a list of URIs for which protection is not enforced by the agent.

See [Not-Enforced URI List in J2EE Agents](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19681-01/820-4803/gataa/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.  There are so many menus that I lose track of what is available in OpenAM.